# How can I create a scaled image from a huge array of values

Tags: java, android, arrays, canvas, bitmap

I am creating a waveform image from a list of volume values, taken from the microphone when recording using a media player.

This works great for recordings that are a couple of minutes long, but when a recording is about an hour long, I get an out of memory error.

I understand that this error is coming from my code where I am trying to create a bitmap image, the width (in pixels) is the length of the array, and the height is always 200 pixels.

Please could someone help me create a method that can take in the large array of int values (from 0 - 100) of n length, and create a scaled bitmap image?

I understand that I would be better off running through smaller chunks of the array and creating a scaled image from that, then maybe appending that onto the main scaled image somehow, but I am struggling.

Here is my code:

```
    public void generateWaveFormImage() {
    try {
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(waveValues.size(), 200, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

        for(int i=0; i<waveValues.size(); i++) {
            canvas.drawLine(i, 100, i, 100-(int)waveValues.get(i), paint);
            canvas.drawLine(i, 100, i, 100 + (int) waveValues.get(i), paint);
        }

        Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmap, 760, 200, true);
        FileManager.saveImage(mShortNameWaveImage, resized);

    } catch(Exception e) {}
    waveValues = new ArrayList();
}
```

This is working great for smaller recordings, ie when the `waveValues` array has 2000 values stored in it.

This is the line throwing the out of memory error

```
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(waveValues.size(), 200, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
```

I would like to add what I have tried so far.

Say the `waveValues` array is 3500 long.

I take the first 1000 values, create a 1000 by 200 image and write the values to that image, then scale down to 760 X 200 and save it.

I then take the next 1000 values and do the same, then append them together, and rescale the image down to 760 x 200.

I then take the next 1000 values, do the same, and append onto the main image, rescale to 760, then do the same for the last 500 values.

This results in creating an incorrectly scaled image, the first 2 images are scaled too much, the third image is correct, and the last image is scaled to a bigger image, which makes for a very weird and wonderful waveform.

Answer (score 0):

In-memory bitmaps are stored without compression, in RGB_565 it is 2 bytes per point, if your image is 2000 width * 200 height = 400k points *2 = 800 kilobytes of data - you should have OOM errors on much bigger images.
Any way, you have to rescale your data before drawing, but not after - what's the use of drawing full-sized points and then relay on image-specific methods of rescaling?

```
double scaleFactor = (double) 760/waveValues.size(); //This will fit all your points inside 760px resolution
for(int i=0; i<waveValues.size(); i++) {
        canvas.drawLine((int) (i*scaleFactor), 100, (int) (i*scaleFactor), 100 - (int)waveValues.get(i), paint);
        canvas.drawLine((int) (i*scaleFactor), 100, (int) (i*scaleFactor), 100 + (int)waveValues.get(i), paint);
    }
```

And for sure, you can do it twice faster with one draw operation:

```
double scaleFactor = (double) 760/waveValues.size(); //This will fit all your points inside 760px resolution
for(int i=0; i<waveValues.size(); i++) {
        canvas.drawLine((int) (i*scaleFactor), 100 - (int)waveValues.get(i), (int) (i*scaleFactor), 100 + (int)waveValues.get(i), paint);           
    }
```

Now, if you have 76 points, each line will be 10px width.

If you have 7600 points, each line will be 0.1px width so 10 lines in 1px

And you image will allways stay inside 760x200

BTW you should be sure that your values are allways inside 0..100, otherwise you will have clipping (lines will fall outside the picture)

Comment: Thank you so much, you are a life saver!!! I can't believe it was that simple! I guess it needed some fresh eyes, so thank you very much, i greatly appreciate it. You are right about the RGB_565, originally I had this set to ARGB_8888, which caused all sorts of memory problems, so I changed it to RGB_565, but some people are still having problems, especially if the waveValues array has got of 500,000 values in it. Thanks again, kind regards, Neil

Comment: On win32 jvm32 can access about 1.4-1.8 Gb, on linux32 it is about 2Gb, on win64 jvm32 can access about 4Gb but with some limits. Any way you should consider using jvm64 if you need more than 1.4Gb of RAM in one thread/one object. While 500k points in 200px height is just 100mp = 200Mb in 565 format, different rescale functions can create large buffers, consuming ram, also make sure that you dispose unneeded bitmaps/canvases - even single memory leak of bitmap means that your ram will be filled in moments.

Answer (score 0):

Not only will a large bitmap cause you memory issues, but rendering every sample will also do a lot of unneeded work as you will just be drawing over the top of the same pixels over and over.

The best way to handle this is to first set a size limit to the bitmap. In the example below that is 2000 pixels, When the sample count is less than this the bitmap will size to the sample count. If the sample count is greater than the bitmap will be limited to 2000 pixels.

For long samples where each pixel column will cover many samples you only need to draw the max value of the samples covered by that column. So keep a variable `x` that is the current sample converted to the pixel location.

When the value `x` is the same as the previous iterations x then just get the max via `max = Math.max(waveValues.get(i));`

When the x value changes to the next column you then render the max. That max is the max sample value for the previous column. You then reset the max value to the current sample.

At the end of the loop you need to render the last column.

As this will only save you time when the number of samples per column is greater than about 1.5 (estimated) you should only use that max value method at that point. In the example I have set it to 2 or more samples per column.

```
public void generateWaveFormImage() {
    try {
        int samples = waveValues.size();
        int width = Math.min(2000, samples);
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, 200, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        double samplesPerColumn = samples / width;
        int x;
        // if not downsampling much then render as normal
        if(samplesPerColumn < 2.0){
            for(int i=0; i < waveValues.size(); i++) {
                x = (int)(i / samplesPerColumn);
                canvas.drawLine(x, 100- (int) waveValues.get(i), x, 100 + (int) waveValues.get(i), paint);
            }
        }else{  // if down sampling then render the max value for every samplesPerColumn
            double max = 0;
            int lastX = -1;
            for(int i=0; i<waveValues.size(); i++) {
                x = (int)(i / samplesPerColumn);
                if(x != lastX){
                    if(i != 0){
                       canvas.drawLine(x - 1, 100 - (int) max, x - 1, 100 + (int) max, paint);
                    }
                    max = waveValues.get(i);
                }else{
                    max = Math.max(max,waveValues.get(i)); 
                }
                lastX = x;
             }
             canvas.drawLine(x - 1, 100 - (int) max, x - 1, 100 + (int) max, paint);
        }



        Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmap, 760, 200, true);
        FileManager.saveImage(mShortNameWaveImage, resized);

    } catch(Exception e) {}

}
```